# How to connect points in a binary image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have a binary image with several points as below:

[image]

How can I make a connection between these points? Like this:

[image]

I have tried

```
se = strel('line', LEN, DEG); 
imclose(image, se);
```

But nothing is changed.

Please help me

Thank you

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example? I.e., we don't know how you get `LEN` and `DEG`...

Comment: Post some more code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`roipoly`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roipoly.html) to create a mask defined by the points.
Given a binary mask you can use `bwmorph(BW,'remove');` to get the boundary and you are done.

The only problem is determining the order of the points, different order defines different mask. This one you'll have to figure for yourself.

Example of ambiguity in ordering the points:
[image]